# How to make my flashdisk write-protected so no one can format it?

Tags: usb-drive, format

Can you help me? I want to make my flashdisk write protected. So no one can format my flashdisk because the data inside the flashdisk is important.

Comment: If data is important you make a backup. If it is even more important you make 2 backups. And if it is very very important you also make sure the backup is never in the same place as the original.

Comment: Listen to the words of Rinzwind, they are wise.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want someone to format your flashdisk then dont give them access to it. Even if your flashdisk has a hardware switch for write protection like SD-Card has, any one can easily use it to turn-off write protection. So your best bet is to keep your flash safe in your drawer and lock the drawer.

I would suggest you get your self some cloud storage and keep you important files there. There are free services available like DropBox.

And just for sake of information, here is a list of flashdrives with physical write protection buttons http://www.fencepost.net/2010/03/usb-flash-drives-with-hardware-write-protection/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. At best, you can remove write permissions from files (at a filesystem level), so you cannot accidentally remove or overwrite the file.

I haven't seen write-protected USB Flash drives, but media like a SD card have such a protection switch. If the data is really important, make copies (backups) of the data and/ or store it on a SD card. After saving the changes and safely removing the media from your computer (Eject / Unmount), toggle the switch to make it read-only.